# Abnormally long "summaries" in search

Tags: bug, design, search

One of these is not like the others:

> [image: results of search]

---

Well, it's not the only one; it was just "getting started"... My search for [`title:"getting started"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=104&tab=votes&q=title%3a%22getting%20started%22) is just lousy with similarly long summaries found later in the results:

```html
<!-- There are too many long summaries... -->
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIpfK.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dctU5.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a9pR.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeitM.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvupv.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSaJX.png">
```

Why are [some results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114515/) so long? They're not *summaries*, it's actually the ENTIRE post being displayed!

Strangely enough, the same results may appear normally in other searches:

- Bad: [`title:"with the superdevmode" title:"getting started"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22with+the+superdevmode%22+is%3Aq+title%3A%22getting+started%22)
- Good: [`title:"with the superdevmode"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22with+the+superdevmode%22)

---

The comments have indicated that a number of other queries trigger the bug. I'm including some of them, and also adding some of my own, some of which are from other sites on the network:

[Help me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20is%3aq%20title%3a%22help%20me%22) there's just [too much](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3a%22too%20much%22) that [doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3a%22doesn%27t%20work%22)! The list is [very long](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22very+long%22), mostly [grammatically correct](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22grammatically+correct%22+closed%3Ano+title%3Avs), and shows [too many](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22too+many%22)
[extra characters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22extra+characters%22) in a [large text](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=6&tab=votes&q=%20is%3aq%20title%3a%22large%20text%22) block! The bug fix is  [too slow](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3a%22too%20slow%22) or the [one big](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=votes&q=%20is%3aq%20title%3a%22one%20big%22) problem is [too big](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22too+big%22)! [Why would](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=7&tab=Votes&q=%20is%3aq%20title%3a%22why%20would%22) they do this?

---

The longest one I can find is via [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22Too+many%22+title%3AMySQLNonTransientConnectionException). It's so big, I can't fit the entire "summary" in one image (because of the 2MB limit), so you can only see half here:

```html
 <!-- Run at your own risk, really... -->
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/myp9l.png">
```

---

I think I know what's triggering this, actually. It happens when you are searching for a phrase with the `title:` operator (which only returns questions, BTW) and the phrase also occurs in the body. All of the content after that trigger phrase will appear as the "summary", so of course there needs to be enough characters after the phrase appears for the bug to be visible.

(This was also reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174399/323179) on the main meta.)

Comment: [It's only getting started](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dctU5.png). Maybe an Elasticsearch issue with the highlighter?

Comment: Could it be because of the abundance of angle-bracketed tags messing up with some regex-like mechanism?

Comment: @dorukayhan I considered the option, but it affects other posts without angle brackets. I have included more images (including Code Caster's).

Comment: More data. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22large+data%22 http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+title%3A%22very+unlikely%22

Comment: All the examples I find consist of (at least) two words, each of which has at least 4 letters. Kind of weird.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I only see the first 5/6 lines, not 20.

Comment: I can reproduce with more search strings like; ["Large text"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22large+text%22), ["too long"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22too+long%22), ["too big"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22too+big%22), the irony is complete :). I took the link from Steve Bennett as starting point.

Comment: It also occurs for two three letter words:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22one+two%22.

Comment: here's another good one: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22too+many+connections%22

Comment: one with a two-letter word: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22find+me%22

Comment: Maybe it's to make bad questions more noticeable. It's a feature!

Comment: I see I should ask getting started questions. Those bring at least 23 upvotes.

Comment: Inspired by @SteveBennett's search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22too+many%22 About halfway down the page you'll find what might be the most extreme example here.

Comment: @JimV I'm not sure what's more disturbing, the triple wall of text question itself or its vote score of +6 (6/0).

Comment: I was able to reproduce this, good catch. In my opinion there are many aspects of search that could benefit from improvement or at the very least oversight. There has been some progress in the past on *looking* into improving search but no real progress in making changes. I know that search isn't exactly at the core of Q&A, but having an improved search feature would greatly benefit the site.

Comment: @TravisJ I agree, search isn't the core *of Q & A*, but it is still very important. It's supposed to help us thwart duplicates, but it's just a pain really. There needs to be some more priority to fixing it.

Comment: @JoeFriend I am still able to reproduce this bug. See [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+title%3A%22Too+many%22+title%3AMySQLNonTransientConnectionException), for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was fixed yesterday when Nick Craver updated Search to Elastic 5.6.1: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301293/263422

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be fixed, thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 11):

As codecaster [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327327/abnormally-long-summaries-in-search#comment363797_327327), this is a [bug with the ElasticSearch highlighter](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7944). Elastic is returning more text than it should be, which is what we are seeing.

As such, it isn't something we can fix ourselves.

We are, however, in the process of updating Elastic to a more current version. Once the upgrade, there is a good chance the issue will be resolved.

Comment: We are not on Elasticsearch 5 yet.

Comment: for reference, now we are on ElasticSearch 5: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357090/1033581

Answer (score 3):

Just looking at the various results, it seems like the root of the "problem" is the summary generator trying to include (highlight) all instances of the search terms in the search snippet (or at least as many as it can up to some internal count). It also has some word count limit, but for the most lengthy of summaries, it also seems to count `code` blocks as one "word", so the limit is still not "exceeded" no matter how long the block is.

It's almost certainly a feature to prevent breaking up `<code>` tags and the code they contain. Maybe to not break any syntax highlighters that might go over the summaries (not that they do normally, but they might at some point)?

The summaries that are abnormally long but without `code` tags or similar HTML blocks seem to be extra long because the search terms occur at the extremes of what the summary generator is willing to show, then it pads out the word count just a little more so the snippet doesn't cut off right at the search term but includes a bit more context after it.

Not sure what the solution to this all would be - the summary generator could try to break up long text with search terms on opposite ends of the potential summary (inserting at `...` in the middle to indicate the break). Ignoring HTML tags altogether and allowing `code` blocks (etc.) to be cut off mid-block would solve the other problem, but break anyone who had built syntax highlighting or other features to run off the summaries that requires complete blocks...

Comment: Stack Overflow is not open source, so speculation about the source of this issue is hardly useful. I know I did the same in comments, but that's why it was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is not correct. Some of the questions displaying the bug have no code AND the key phrase only occurs at the beginning of the post. The summary generator should be inserting the ellipsis already as it would when everything works right.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I figures since the question was simply about "why are some results so long" finding the linking factor among all the bug examples would qualify as an explanation, albeit not a technical one.

Comment: @Laurel - The none `code` examples do still have large HTML blocks that would be interpreted by the summary generator as a single "word"

Comment: @BrianNorth As a site dedicated to programming, we have a lot of code, including markup languages like HTML. You're merely seeing circumstantial evidence; there are questions without code that exhibit the bug, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22getting+started%22+unity+framework).