# Search results missing in close as duplicate because it has no answers

Tags: bug, status-declined, search, flag-dialog

I was trying to close something as a duplicate, and I thought it would be real quick to use `user:me score:100` to find questions that were mine with a score of 100. Unfortunately, it was not the case; I only see [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327327) of my two 100+ scored posts:

[image: 1 result]

(The equivalent search is `user:6083675 score:100` for everyone one else.)

If I use regular search, I get the right results, including [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331867):

[image: 2 results]

After looking into this more I think this is because it has no answers. On the main site, this would usually be a good thing (because you [can’t normally close against unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux)) but on Meta it is possible (and encouraged) to close questions as duplicates of unanswered questions. This also affects edge cases on the main site such as when the same user asks the same question again and you want to close it as a duplicate of their earlier question.

See also my other (MSE) post on this: [Show unanswered questions in the duplicate dialog on meta sites and in other cases where choosing an unanswered target is allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284733/323179)

Comment: See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux) on MSE.